# Consolidate several Parallel.ForEach into one in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

`Parallel.ForEach` is blocking until all threads return. Each objectType below is actually a list. Is there any way to use `Parallel.ForEach` just once in this scenario? Please advise.

```
Main(){
    List<Type1> objectType1 = ...
        List<Type2> objectType2 = ...
        List<Type3> objectType3 = ...

    Parallel.ForEach(objectType1, MyFunction)
    Parallel.ForEach(objectType2, MyFunction)
    Parallel.ForEach(objectType3, MyFunction)
}
```

EDIT:
This is MyFunction:

```
MyFunction (object arg) {

    //some code here

    if (arg is Type1) { ProcessType1(arg as Type1); }

    else if (arg is Type2) { ProcessType2(arg as Type2); }

    else if (arg is Type3) { ProcessType3(arg as Type3); }

    //some more code here
}
```

Comment: Are `MyFunction` all the same function, in each case?

Comment: Why type does MyFunction operate on? If they all operate on the same type, combine your lists into a single list and call Parallel.ForEach on each item.

Comment: small hint: instead of `is` and then `as`, you can as well do `var t1 = arg as Type1; if (arg != null) ProcessType1(t1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concat. The way you are going to do it depends on the type of `Type01`, `Type02` and `Type03`. I am going to assume they are custom classes, so you can do like this:

```
public class X { }
public class Y { }
public class Z { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var l1 = new List<X> { new X() };
    var l2 = new List<Y> { new Y() };
    var l3 = new List<Z> { new Z() };

    var master = new List<dynamic>();

    master.AddRange(l1);
    master.AddRange(l2);
    master.AddRange(l3);

    Parallel.ForEach(master,
        val =>
        {
            var isX = val is X;
        });
}
```

If your problem is repeating the same function then you can store the function body into `Action<dynamic>`

```
Action<dynamic> action =
    (val) =>
    {
        var isX = val is X;
    };
```

And call

```
Parallel.ForEach(yourList, action);
```

Answer (score 6):

For the pseudo-code you've written above, `Type1`, `Type2` and `Type3` would all have to be convertible to a common type, the type of the parameter to the `MyFunction` method.  If they all have a common base type, and you are really calling `MyFunction` for all of them then you can combine the sequences using LINQ:

```
Parallel.ForEach(objectType1.Concat<BaseType>(objectType2).Concat(objectType3),
    MyFunction);
```

and `MyFunction` looks like:

```
public void MyFunction(BaseType baseType)
{
    // Process base type...
}
```

Comment: You could even use `object` as the common base type, but that's some ugly casting then.

Answer (score 1):

You could combined them by casting to object and using Concat

```
List<object> combined = one.Cast<object>()
    .Concat<object>(two.Cast<object>())
    .Concat(three.Cast<object>())
    .ToList();
```

I would also note that using reflection like that is probably an indication of some bad design decisions. If possible you should extract a common interface that each of the different types implements. Such as something like:

```
interface IProcessable
{
    void Process();
}

class Type1 : IProcessable
{
    public void Process(){ //stuff }
}

class Type2 : IProcessable
{
    public void Process(){ //stuff }
}
```

Then you would just have an `IEnumerable<IProcessable>` that you would do:

```
Parallel.Foreach(listOfStuff, Process);
```